# The meaning of almost surely convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider the space of sequences of tosses of a fair coin. In particular let $X_{nH}$ be the number of times that a coin lands on heads in a sequence of $n$ coin flips.

Consider statement $S$ below.

$S$ : In the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ almost surely $X_{n}/n \rightarrow 0.5 $.

It seems clear that it is not the case that in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the
probability $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}/n = 0.5) \rightarrow 1$ since if $n$ is odd it is clear
that $X_{n}/n \neq 0.5$.  So does statement $S$ mean that for each $n$ there exists a
measurable neighbourhood $N_{n}$ about $0.5$ such that with probability 1 each 
$X_{n}/n \in N_n$ and that $N_{n}$ is decreasing with $n$?

The other subtlety lies in the definition of $X_{nH}$. I am not sure whether this definition indicates that we are to generate all sequences of coin flips then choose a sequence of length $n$ at random and measure how close $X_{nH}$ is to 0.5 for ever increasing $n$.  Or does this definition mean choose  a sequence length $n$ and calculate $X_{nH}$ then flip the coin again and calculate $X_{n+1H}$ for the original sequence plus an extra coin flip.  Of course these two interpretations of the definition could really be the same!

In summary I've been thinking for a while about the meaning of this (and a few other) almost surely statement(s) and I can't progress without understanding these very basic but fundamental questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost sure convergence of a sequence of random variables means that P(Limit holds)=1. So, in your case, $\frac{X_n}{n}\rightarrow 0.5\space a.s.$ means $P(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_n}{n}= 0.5)=1$ This statement is meant to be interpreted given an *entire sequence* of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ values (i.e, each realization of an infinite sequence of tosses is **1** sample point/object). What is says is that, except for a coutable set of sequences, each sequence of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ values satistifes the regular/real analysis definition of the [limit of a sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence). You state:

*"So does statement S  mean that for each n  there exists a measurable neighbourhood $N_n$   about 0.5  such that with probability 1 each $\frac{X_n}{n}\in N_n$   and that $N_n$   is decreasing with n ?*

This statement is more like the weak law of large numbers, or *convergence in probability*, which states $P(|\frac{X_n}{n}-0.5|<\epsilon)\rightarrow1,\forall \epsilon>0$. For almost sure convergence, what matters is that for almost all sequences ($X_{i,n}$):

$\space\exists N_{i,j}: |\frac{X_{i,n}}{n}-0.5|<N_{i,j},\forall n\geq j$ where $i\in[0,1]$ is a continuous index for the infinite sequence of coin tosses.

Basically, its saying that almost all sequences (i.e, trajectories) approach 0.5 in the same sense that a normal sequence would. This is the key difference between the weak and strong law of large numbers: weak law only says that most of the $\frac{X_n}{n}$ *values* for a given $n$ will be close to 0.5, while the strong law talks about an entire sample trajectory (single infinite run of tosses), and states that most *trajectories* get close to 0.5 and *stay* close, which is something the weak law does not guarantee -- it just says the most of the trajectory values will be close to 0.5, but not that they have to stay close for any given trajectory, (i.e, $\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} > N_n$, which the strong law says only happens a *countably* infinite number of times, so P($\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} > N_n)=0$

Comment: Thanks for the detail that you've taken the trouble to give.  I guess my understandings mostly stem from a misconception about what one *sample* is exactly.

Comment: Exactly - samples are *points* in WLLN and entire *trajectories* in SLLN.

Comment: @user76844 I understand from your wonderful answer that almost all possible trajectories of the infinitely long experiment of random events will go to a limiting value of 0.5 as $n \to \infty$ BUT for a countable trajectories which may have a different limit or may diverge. Is this countable finite? Or could it be countable but infinite? Thanks in advance!